# Expand product of symbolic sums (with identically named indices)

Tags: symbolic, summation, rule

I have an expression that is a product of two symbolic sums.

```
Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}]*Sum[b[k], {k, 1, n}]
```

How can I expand this expression? I want to see something like this:

```
Sum[Sum[a[k1]*b[k2], {k2, 1, n}], {k1, 1, n}]
```

If the running indices weren't the same, I would try to fashion a transformation rule to match the situation above. But here, I'd have to create a *new* symbol, so I am unsure where to even start.

Comment: "I'd have to create a new symbol" - this is where the built-in dummy variable `K` comes in handy; you can just systematically replace indices with `K[1]`, `K[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, a double sum can be written with a single `Sum`. With this we make a replacement:

```
   Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}]*Sum[b[k], {k, 1, n}] /. 
     Sum[a1_, {a2_, 1, n}] Sum[b1_, {b2_, 1, n}] :> 
      Sum[(a1 /. a2 -> k1) (b1 /. b2 -> k2), {k1, 1, n}, {k2, 1, n}]
```

[image]